# Proc Freq Combine Results Rows based on Contents

Tags: sas

I am doing a Proc Freq on a a large amount of User Entered Data, I would like to know if I can Combine the Results Rows based on the Contents of the first column.

Comment: if you can show your sample input and output. someone can help you. it is very difficult to guess otherwise what exactly you want

Comment: Input doesn't matter. The output is just a normal Proc Freq. So, a Table with Frequency numbers and percentages. The first Column would be what I put into the  'Tables' option for proc freq, say, 2 Rows First Column contained Nyfaria, but one was 'Nyfaria - January' and the other was 'Nyfaria - February', I would like it so the Output shows them Combined into just 'Nyfaria'. Would like to be able to do this inside the Proc Freq statement.

Comment: Then use the sashelp.class step and show what you get and what you want. It's not clear at the moment. Please refer to [ask]

Comment: Are there 2 kinds of SAS? because I am being Very Clear about what I want...

Comment: If it's clear to others you'll get an answer I suppose, it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to perform a frequency of the first word (or 1st  `scan`ned part of a column). Such a case will require data manipulation to reduce the longer value to the desired shortened value, in a different variable, to be frequency binned.

```
data have;
  input;
  user_entered_data = _infile_;
  datalines;
Nyfaria - January
Nyfaria - Febuary
Michelangelo - January
Michelangelo - Feburary
run;

data have_for_freq;
  set have;
  item = scan (user_entered_data,1,' ');
run;

options nocenter;
ods noproctitle;

proc freq data=have_for_freq;
  title "Freq of raw data";
  table user_entered_data;
run;

proc freq data=have_for_freq;
  title "Freq of raw data formatted as $4.";
  table user_entered_data;
  format user_entered_data $4.;
run;

proc freq data=have_for_freq;
  title "Freq of raw data - item scanned out";
  table item;
run;
```

[image]

Note: In some cases you can use a `format` to control the mapping of a raw value to a reported value.  There is no format that returns the first 'word' of a value (such as `scan` does)